# MSBuild K2 build failure - MSB0001 - "Task Instance should be null"

Tags: msbuild, k2

I have multiple K2 workflow projects which build fine in VS2012. When I attempt to deploy any using VS I simply get a Build Failed message. When I attempt to do a command line build and deploy I get...

> Microsoft.Build.Share.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal
>   MSBuild Error: Task Instance should be null at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInternalError(....

I am unable to find any info about this error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I found that MSBuild had been set up to use a system environment variable called Environment then match that to a K2 server environment name. I hadn't set up a K2 environment with the correct name. I did this using the K2 Workspace Management Console and now my project deploys successfully.